# SNAP: Simulation and Neuroscience Application Platform

Tags: ffmpeg, simulation, neuroscience

Is there any documentation/help manual on how to use SNAP (Simulation and Neuroscience Application Platform)[1](https://github.com/sccn/SNAP).

I wanted to run the Motor Imagery sample scenario with a .avi file for the stimulus instead of the image. How can that be done?

The following error is obtained when using the AlphaCalibration scenario which gives code to play an avi file.Any help appreciated

```
:movies:ffmpeg(warning): parser not found for codec indeo4, packets or times may be invalid.
:movies:ffmpeg(warning): max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000
:movies(error): Could not open /e/BCI_Feb2014/SNAP-master/src/studies/SampleStudy/bird.avi
:audio(error): Cannot open file: /e/BCI_Feb2014/SNAP-master/src/studies/SampleStudy/bird.avi
:audio(error): Could not open audio /e/BCI_Feb2014/SNAP-master/src/studies/SampleStudy/bird.avi
:movies:ffmpeg(warning): parser not found for codec indeo4, packets or times may be invalid.
:movies:ffmpeg(warning): max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000
:movies(error): Could not open /e/BCI_Feb2014/SNAP-master/src/studies/SampleStudy/bird.avi
:gobj(error): Texture "/e/BCI_Feb2014/SNAP-master/src/studies/SampleStudy/bird.avi" exists but cannot be read.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\BCI_Feb2014\SNAP-master\src\framework\latentmodule.py", line 458, in _run_wrap
    self.run()
  File "modules\BCI\AlphaCalibration.py", line 30, in run
Exception during run():
    m = self.movie(self.moviefile, block=False, scale=[0.7,0.4],aspect=1.125,contentoffset=[0,0],volume=0.3,timeoffset=self.begintime+t*self.awake_duration,looping=True)
Could not load texture: bird.avi
  File "E:\BCI_Feb2014\SNAP-master\src\framework\basicstimuli.py", line 348, in movie
    tex = self._engine.base.loader.loadTexture(filename)
  File "E:\BCI_Feb2014\Panda3D-1.8.0\direct\showbase\Loader.py", line 554, in loadTexture
    raise IOError, message
IOError: Could not load texture: bird.avi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video files are not included in the github repository due to the file size. However, your use case should work if you use any other video file that you put on the search path (e.g., next to the other media files - see also Panda3d's notion of content search paths).

There is a SNAP release including media files at: ftp://sccn.ucsd.edu/pub/software/LSE-SDK/ which might include the files you're looking for.